# On using modal for lightning, the width of the modal is not increasing on increase of content

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, lightning, modal

I have a component which displays model. The model is getting successfully display but the content is not displayed completely. 
In the content I display a table. On increase in column value or increase the number of column, the content gets disappear.

below is the sample code

```
<aura:component controller="IndirectAddContactWrapper">
    <aura:attribute name="contactsList" type="IndirectAddContactWrapper[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acnt" type="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="storeVisit" type="Store_Visit__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="hiddenValue" type="String" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact'}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Salutation" type="String[]" default="Mr., Ms., Mrs., Dr., Prof."/>


    <aura:attribute name="FirstName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="LastName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="Email" type="String" />



    <aura:attribute name="modalValue" type="String" default="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open"/>
 <!--  <aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:IndirectAddContactEvent"/>  -->
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" default="Add Contacts for this Visit"/>
    <aura:attribute name="closable" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="closeLabel" type="String" default="Close"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="confirmLabel" type="String" default="Done"/>
     <aura:attribute name="Div1visiblity" type="String" default="slds-show"/> 


    <aura:attribute name="onclose" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.defaultCloseAction}"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="onconfirm" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.createContact}"/>
     <aura:attribute name="onconfirmAdd" type="Aura.Action" default="{!c.AddContact}"/>
    <div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-m-top--x-small">
     <div aria-hidden="{!v.hiddenValue}" role="dialog" class="{!v.modalValue}">
      <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">{!v.title}</h2>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.closable}">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close" onclick="{!v.onclose}">
                        <c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/SLDS100/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close" 
                                               category="standard" 
                                               size="small" 
                                               name="close" />

                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">{!v.closeLabel}</span>
                                </button>
                            </aura:if>
          </div>

          <div class="slds-modal__content"> 
              <div class="{!v.Div1visiblity}">

            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactsList}" var="cnt">           
                <tbody>
                <tr >     
                 <td class="cell">
                     <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!cnt.checked}" /> 

                 </td>
                    <td class="cell">
                        <ui:outputText value="{!cnt.contactObj.FirstName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell">
                        <ui:outputText value="{!cnt.contactObj.LastName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell">
                        <ui:outputText value="{!cnt.contactObj.Email}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell">
                        <ui:outputText value="{!cnt.contactObj.Phone}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </aura:iteration>
            </table>
                  <br/> 
                  <div class="slds-text-align--center">
                   <a href="#" aura:id="{!stv.Id}" onclick="{!c.AddNewScreen}">Add Contacts</a>
               </div>
            </div >


          </div>         
          <div class="{!v.Div1visiblity}">
          <div class="slds-modal__footer"> 
               <div >

                  <div>
                       <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.onconfirmDone}">Done</button>
                   </div>
               </div>    
           </div>
           </div> 


         </div>

          </div>

         <div class="slds-modal-backdrop slds-modal-backdrop--open"></div>   
    </div>
     <!-- <div aura:id="ModalDialogNewContact" /> -->
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you get solution for this?

Comment: Did you resolve?